# Can I frame and insulate over EPS panels?

Tags: insulation, basement

My house came with 1/2 inch EPS board already attached to concrete in our basement. Instead of ripping down, I would like to frame over foam with 2x4 studs and fill with rockwool. Per code I need R13 minimum in zone 4A. Is keeping the EPS board on concrete a problem here?

Comment: I would just leave the XPS in place and put the batts in over top of the XPS.  What was your plan for a vapor barrier?

Comment: This question is fairly common. Here's [a related question](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/190869/rigid-board-installed-after-framing-in-interior-basement-walls-should-i-be-con?rq=1).

Comment: No, not a problem at all.  There is a few things to consider with the overall assembly however.  Here is a good resource, with more links at the end.  https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwjakp6xie3uAhXFvp4KHWqvA8IQFjAUegQIIhAC&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.energystar.gov%2Fsites%2Fdefault%2Ffiles%2Fasset%2Fdocument%2FBSC%2520Information%2520Sheet%2520511%2520Basement%2520Insulation%2520for%2520all%2520Climates.pdf&usg=AOvVaw07OmUnxMUYjfaVz3YIGElX   And yes, the rockwool is a great substitute for unfaced batt mentioned in the assembly diagram.

Comment: @Blobfish -- maybe you could expand that comment into an answer?